# Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

Im creating a symfony console command to auto select a winner from participant entries to run via cron every day.

The execute function looks like this

```
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

        $this->today = new \DateTime();
        $this->today = $this->today->format('Y-m-d');

        $this->container = $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer();
        $participant = $this->container->get('smack_calendar.data_collection_repository')
            ->findOneBy(array('entryDate' => $this->today ));
```

}

when executing

```
 app/console foo:pickwinner --test daily
```

I get this error

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]   Error: Call
>   to a member function format() on a non-object

on this line

```
->findOneBy(array('entryDate' => $this->today ));
```

Im not a big symfony user and never touched doctrine before so forgive me if this is a stupid question :D

Comment: What $participant is supposed to return? All the daily participant(s)?

Comment: If entryDate is a date field, you should simply use a DateTime object. You don't need to format it. So, just remove the ->format(...) line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with dates using doctrine always work with DateTime objects, so:

```
$this->container = $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer();
$participant = $this->container->get('smack_calendar.data_collection_repository')
        ->findOneBy(array('entryDate' => new \DateTime('now') ));
```

PS Create objects in a fly, especially mutable.